# Microphone progress bar in action script

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, mxml, mxmlc

Any microphone action script code which indicates a progress bar when there is activity on microphone

Comment: Do you mean a spectrum computation? Indicating volume through use of a progress bar? similar to the one built into the flash player when fiddling with settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's some code you can use:

it uses the graphics API to draw the indication of volume

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><mx:Application 
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
    layout="absolute" 
    width="450" 
    height="450"
    creationComplete="creationComplete_Handler()">

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import flash.media.Microphone;
        import flash.events.ActivityEvent;
        import flash.events.Event;
        import flash.events.StatusEvent;

        private var _mic:Microphone;

        private function creationComplete_Handler():void
        {
            _mic = Microphone.getMicrophone();
            _mic.setLoopBack(true);

            _mic.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, mic_ActivateEventHandler);
            _mic.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, mic_StatusEventHandler);
            _mic.addEventListener(ActivityEvent.ACTIVITY, mic_ActivityEventHandler);

        }

        private function mic_ActivateEventHandler(e:Event):void
        {
            lblStatus.text = "mic active!";
        }

        private function mic_StatusEventHandler(e:StatusEvent):void
        {
            trace("ststus event: " + e.toString()); 
        }

        private function mic_ActivityEventHandler(e:ActivityEvent):void
        {
            trace("Activity Event");
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, mic_EnterFrame_EventHandler);
        }

        private function mic_EnterFrame_EventHandler(e:Event):void
        {
            lblMicLevel.text = "Mic Level :"+_mic.activityLevel.toString();
            micLevelCanvas.graphics.clear();

            micLevelCanvas.graphics.beginFill(000000, 1);
            micLevelCanvas.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, (_mic.activityLevel * 2), 20);
            micLevelCanvas.graphics.endFill();
        }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>




<mx:Label x="10" y="10" id="lblStatus"/>
<mx:Canvas x="10" y="36" width="200" height="20" id="micLevelCanvas" />
<mx:Label x="10" y="64" id="lblMicLevel"/></mx:Application>
```

Comment: @Rajeev I have tested it on IE and it works like a charm, do you have an error? can you post it here?